# Difference between docker pull complete vs download complete

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know

> pull complete

is reached after

> download complete

in lifecycle but I am interested in knowing the difference between them. I tried searching internet but couldn't found anything clearly explaining the differences.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When pulling a remote docker image, you can see that the layers are downloaded. After a layer is downloaded, docker shows a status of extracting the image which is mainly uncompressing the layer and verifying its checksum. Once this is done the layer is maked with `Pull complete`.

So in short, `Download complete` means the layer is downloaded whereas `Pull complete` implies that the layer was downloaded and extracted onto the host machine.

Comment: sounds logical but is there any documentation that can be referred?

Answer (score 11):

There may not be any formal documentation about the difference between these messages, but you can always go directly to the source code: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/distribution/xfer/download.go

You can see in the source that it updates the status to "Pull complete" after calling `archive.DecompressStream` (during which the "Extracting" status is displayed).